# How to form Html response from play.mvc.Results.redirect("/auth/authenticate/facebook") call?

Tags: playframework-2.3, securesocial

Here I do redirect call to Facebook login page  that returns as 'play.mvc.Result' Object but I require as 'play.twirl.api.Html'

```
public class SecureSocialTemplatesPlugin implements ViewTemplates {

    @Override
    public Html getLoginPage(Form<Tuple2<String, String>> arg0, Option<String> arg1, RequestHeader arg2, Lang arg3) {

      play.mvc.Results.redirect("/auth/authenticate/facebook");//Issue here is this call returns play.mvc.Result object but I require Html
      return sociallogin.render(socialSite);
    }
}
```

How to generate html response from redirect call response?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, you should return the [Result](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html) (as for every Play action - actually [redirect(...)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html#redirect(play.mvc.Call)) is Result too), so it should be:

```
public Html getLoginPage(Form<Tuple2<String, String>> arg0, Option<String> arg1, RequestHeader arg2, Lang arg3) {
    // ...
    return play.mvc.Results.redirect("/auth/authenticate/facebook");
}
```

Comment: No. This is not controller action. I have been using SecureSocial framework for social login. As part of securesocial implementation my SecureSocialTemplatesPlugin class implements 'securesocial.controllers.ViewTemplates' interface. So I have to override its methods. I can not change method's return type.